# iOS Font loading problem

Tags: ios, uifont, custom-font

Helle every one !

I have added din.otf font in my iOS project.
Then in my plist I have :

[image]

Now when I want to use it I juste have to write this line :

```
lalel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"din" size:12.f];
```

Am I right ? It doen't work at all ...
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to list all fonts that are available on your device after importing by adding this piece of code :

(taken from : http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/)

Legacy Answer

```
// List all fonts on iPhone
  NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
  NSArray *fontNames;
  NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
  for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
  {
      NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
      fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
          [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
          [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
      for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
      {
          NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
      }
      [fontNames release];
  }
  [familyNames release];
```

And try to search for your font name.

// End Legacy Answer

I've found a way to load font at runtime which does not involve to add it on the .plist file.

```
+ (void)loadFontAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
    if(data == nil)
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Failed to load font. Data at path is null path = %@", path);
#endif //ifdef Debug
        return;
    }
    CFErrorRef error;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
    CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
    if(!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)){
#ifdef DEBUG
        CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
        NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
        CFRelease(errorDescription);
        return;
#endif //ifdef Debug
    }
    CFStringRef fontName = CGFontCopyFullName(font);
    NSLog(@"Loaded: %@", fontName);
    [[self sharedInstance] addFont:font withName:(NSString *)fontName];

    CFRelease(fontName);
    CFRelease(font);
    CFRelease(provider);
}

+ (void) unloadFont:(NSString*) fontName
{
    CFErrorRef error;
    CGFontRef fontref = [[self sharedInstance] getFontWithName:fontName];
    if(fontref)
    {
        CTFontManagerUnregisterGraphicsFont(fontref, &error);
        [[self sharedInstance] removeFontWithName:(NSString *)fontName];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"WARNING: Font cannot be unloaded: %@", fontName);
    }
}
```

And you can just use the name that NSLog(@"Loaded: %@", fontName); output.

Comment: If you have set up everything (added the font the plist file and added it on your project), this bit of code can show you which fonts are embed in the application (plus the system one). Just add it to your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method and you'll have the list. After that it's just a matter of finding the name of the font in the list.

Comment: Hi Morkrom. This was the start of the solution for me. The final bit I had to do was select the file, select the file inspector pane and tick the target membership of the target I wanted the file to be included in. Once I did this the font was shown using the method in the question.